# Output order of datagridview cells when exporting to excel

Tags: excel, datagridview, export, closedxml

I have a c# form with a datagridview that I am successfully exporting to Excel
using ClosedXML (to be able to have some kind of "formating" and colored rows/headers
etc.)
Everything works fine except the fact that I am altering the order of my columns with:

`dataGridView1.Columns["tBox_FirstName"].DisplayIndex = 0;`

It works in the datagridview itself, but not when I am exporting it to Excel.
In Excel I have to original order back.

However my renaming in the same realm is exported to Excel flawlessly
`dataGridView1.Columns[32].HeaderText = "Firstname";`

Is there any way that I get the actual (edited) view of the dgv to be exported
to Excel or would my only chance be to alter the DB to have the fields in the
order that I want?